# Plot a step function (cadlag) in R (two dots: continuity and discontinuity point)

Tags: r, plot

Essentially I want to plot a compound Poisson process. Everything works fine except that I don't know how to edit the plot parameters correctly.
I want to have the continuity points with a full dot and the discontinuity points with an empty dot. Right now I only am able to manage the full dot.

Minimal working example (plots an compound Poisson path with 10 jumps)

```
n <- 10
n.t <- cumsum(rexp(n))
x <- c(0,cumsum(rnorm(n)))
plot(stepfun(n.t, x), xlab="t", ylab="X",do.points = TRUE,pch = 16,col.points = "blue",verticals = FALSE)
```

So how can I add the discontinuity points to the right? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `points` to add the points after the original plot.

```
set.seed(2017)      ## For reproducibility

## Your code
n <- 10
n.t <- cumsum(rexp(n))
x <- c(0,cumsum(rnorm(n)))
plot(stepfun(n.t, x), xlab="t", ylab="X",
    do.points = TRUE,pch = 16,col.points = "blue",verticals = FALSE)

## Add the endpoints
points(n.t, x[-length(x)], pch = 1)
```

[image: Step function]

Comment: I first tried it with stepfun itself which didn't work, this is a nice idea,thanks!